# Insert Comment to last cell from another cell Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have wrote a code in VBA Excel 2010 and it works great from sheet2 send data to sheet1 with a button submit.
But I have a cell where after it will be submitted need to send this data to another sheet as a comment for the last cell.
E.x:

```
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rngk = ws2.Range("B5")

com = ws2.Range("B9")
k = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngk, ws2.Range("D5:E6").Value, 2, False)

lastRow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 3) = k
```

Now on the same cell that is equal to k (LastRow, 3) I want to add comment from cell B9 from another sheet.

How can I add the B9 comment to this cell!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried recording the action of inserting a comment and copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that the cell your copying from has a comment using something like `Not SourceCell.Comment Is Nothing`.
If it has a comment then just set the Target cell value to text of the comment.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim TargetCell As Range
    Dim SourceCell As Range


    Set TargetCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H5")
    Set SourceCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B9")

    If HasComment(SourceCell) Then
        TargetCell.Value = SourceCell.Comment.Text
    End If

End Sub

Public Function HasComment(Target As Range) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        With Target
            HasComment = Not .Comment Is Nothing
        End With
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "HasComment()", "Argument must reference single cell."
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " " & Err.Description & " in procedure Module1.HasComment."
            Err.Clear
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Select

End Function
```

## Edit:

This will take the values from `Sheet2` and place in comments on the last row holding data in `Sheet1`:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim TargetColumns As Variant
    Dim SourceCells As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rAddToCell As Range
    Dim x As Long

    TargetColumns = Array(6, 10, 15, 17) 'Column numbers to place into.
    Set SourceCells = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B9,B15,B22,B26")

    'Look at each cell in turn.
    For Each rCell In SourceCells

        'Find the last cell in the correct column.
        Set rAddToCell = LastCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), CLng(TargetColumns(x)))

        'If there's already a comment then delete it first
        'Then add value from SourceCell into comment in Target column.
        With rAddToCell
            If HasComment(rAddToCell) Then
                .ClearComments
            End If
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Text Text:=rCell.Value
        End With

        x = x + 1
    Next rCell

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet, Optional Col As Long = 0) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        If Col = 0 Then
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        Else
            lLastCol = Col '.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Columns(Col).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        End If

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Public Function HasComment(Target As Range) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        With Target
            HasComment = Not .Comment Is Nothing
        End With
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "HasComment()", "Argument must reference single cell."
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " " & Err.Description & " in procedure Module1.HasComment."
            Err.Clear
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: I will use the data inside the cell not the comment from the cell. Practically is a data form compile, after completing the form the B9 is the comment for that group of data. E.x name, surname, evaluation, and the comments for that user.

Comment: Nope, don't get you then....  _I have a cell where after it will be submit need to send this data to the other sheet a comment for the last cell_.  So, you have a cell.... at some point that single cell it will be "submitted".... you need to send the data from that single cell to another sheet.... something about a group of data and comments?  What group of data and where does the comment come in?

Comment: The ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") have all the data...
and the ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") is where the date will be sent and stored. In the sheet2 I have B9, B15, B22, B26 that will be sent to sheet1 as Comments in the lastrow of columns F, J, O, Q, also this columns have data in those  k = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngk, ws2.Range("D5:E6").Value, 2, False
)

Comment: Right... think I get you now.  So `Sheet2!B9 value` goes to `Sheet1!F<last row>` and is inserted as a comment.  Those last row cells will already contain data (result of the VLOOKUP) - irrelevant as the data from Sheet2 is going into it as a comment?

Comment: Will columns F, J, O and Q all have the same last row or might they differ?

Comment: They will differ from the VLOOKUP but you got me right bro.
N = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngn, ws2.Range("D5:E6").Value, 2, False)
q = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngq, ws2.Range("D11:E12").Value, 2, False)
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngy, ws2.Range("D17:E18").Value, 2, False)
Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngz, ws2.Range("D24:E25").Value, 2, False)
These are the data for F, J, O, Q each of them have a vlookup 
They are inserted with ws1.Cells(lastRow, 3) = k as in the code
 :) hope you can help me as is my 1st time programming in VBA

Comment: I've added a second version of code.  NB:  You'll still need to check if the cell is empty in this line of code - `.Comment.Text Text:=rCell.Value`.  If `rcell` is empty it still throws an error.